# How to implement Navbar contex menu

Tags: angular

I have a navbar component which has some application level menus and those will always be visible no matter the page in which the user find him self on.

Further more, the application needs also some contextual navbar menus, again, based on which page the user find him self on.

After thinking about the problem and with my current knowledge, i thought in create a NavbarContextMenuService and in the navbar i would subscribe to this service using observables. Lastly i would inject the NavbarContextMenuService in the components requiring it, either to clear the navbar contextual menu area or to inject the current component's context menu.

I have no code yet to show. My intent is to have a good conceptual starting point so i not end up making unnecessary refactoring later.

Comment: Your idea with the service is correct. You should search for examples using portals from the angular material CDK. See https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im not allowed to use material library. I will post my solution latter!

Comment: Such a restriction makes no sense IMO

Comment: If you are planning to dynamically embed components and no templates, you could also use ngComponentOutlet

Comment: After reading about ngComponentOutlet i end up changing the implementation just a bit, but it became more concise, readable and i learned something new. Thank you for your answers. By the way, do you agree with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Next is my solution, i would appreciate some feedback on the implementation/code quality.

**NavbarContexMenuService**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavbarContextMenuService {

  contextMenu: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {}
}
```

**Navbar Component Template** (here i set a "slot" #contextMenu for the ability to dynamically inject the contextual menu next to the application level menus)

```
  <!-- contextual menu -->
  <ng-template *ngComponentOutlet="contextMenu"></ng-template>

  <!-- notifications menu -->
  <jhi-notifications></jhi-notifications>

  <!-- applications menu -->
  <jhi-applications></jhi-applications>
```

**Navbar Component Class**

```
contextMenu: any;

constructor(
    private navbarContexMenuService: NavbarContextMenuService
  ) {}

ngOnInit() {
     this.navbarContexMenuService.contextMenu.subscribe(ctxMenu => {
     this.contextMenu = ctxMenu;
});
  }
```

**Some Ramdom Component**

```
constructor(private navbarContextMenuService: NavbarContextMenuService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.navbarContextMenuService.contextMenu.next(CmContextMenuComponent);
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // clear navbar contextual menu
    this.navbarContextMenuService.contextMenu.next();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any services, just create a component like `NavBar` and use in your `app-component`. Under that just add `router-outlet` to navigate through your router.

#### App Component

```html
<div>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Im not sure if i understand your sugestion. but based on you code i cant see how i would be able to render dynamic navbar contextual menus